# saving a long number from the user in an array (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, input, long-integer, getline

I need to read from the user the number `1000101` and save in an array.

For example :

```
int array1 [6]={1,0,0,1,0,1};
```

But I need the user to enter the number in one line. any idea how to save one long number from the user in an array?

Answer (score 3):

You can get a line from `std::cin` with e.g. the [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). After you have the line, get one character at a time and check that it is a one or a zero, and then convert it to an integer and add it to your array.

Remember to check the limits of both the string and array, so you don't step outside it.

Comment: One remark: checking for 0 or 1 is part of the example, but it's not clear whether it is part of the question.  If not `isdigit` could be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c;
std::vector<int> number;
while (std::cin >> c)
    if (c == '0' || c == '1')
        number.push_back(c - '0');
    else if (c == '\n')
        break;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("illegal characters in number");
```